# Permission denied when using "make"

Tags: terminal, security

I have been trying to install `p4vasp` via the terminal on a macOS machine. I am following the installation instructions here: https://github.com/orest-d/p4vasp/blob/master/README.MacOS

However, when I try to run "make", I get the following permission denied error:

```
echo "p4vasp_home='/Users/nabil/p4vasp'" >lib/p4vasp/config.py
echo "p4vasp_home='/Users/nabil/p4vasp'" >lib/p4vasp/config.py
/bin/sh: lib/p4vasp/config.py: Permission denied
/bin/sh: lib/p4vasp/config.py: Permission denied
make: *** [p4vasp_config] Error 1
make: *** [p4vasp_config] Error 1
[2]  + exit 2     make
```

I am not familiar with macOS, and I wonder what is causing this problem. I tried giving terminal full access to the disk via system preferences, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Try to run `sudo make local` then `sudo make` and finally  `sudo make install`.  You can search on internet what sudo means, but remember that it will wait that you enter the admin password (don't worry if when you're typing nothings shows up, it is listening to your keyboard)

Comment: Don't recommend people use `sudo` to do things blindly, expecially on files that are in their own $HOME.  Sheesh.

Comment: @dbrane What are the permissions on the directory tree you expanded the files into?  Also, that `echo` is going to fail anyway, because the previous line changes PWD to the src/ directory, and there is no lib/ directory there.  It's one level higher.

Comment: Why is the file using /Users/nabil is nabil your username on the macos machine

Comment: As I noted in your other question - if you are going to build this use another fork. However I would say giving the errors you have I would suggest you don't use this software until you understand macOS more or get someone who does to do the build for you.